# Xcode6 can't run any app in simulator ( Domain = NSPOSIXErrorDomain, Code = 3 )

Tags: ios, xcode6, ios-simulator

No app can run in my simulator, although building is good.

#### Error messsage is below:

> Unable to run app in Simulator
>
> An error was encountered while running (Domain = NSPOSIXErrorDomain, Code = 3)

Comment: This might be under NDA. I suggest checking the Apple Developer Forums.

Comment: restart xcode and simulator, reboot mac if that doesn't help

Comment: @bensarz I change the version of simulator from 8 to 7.1, now it works fine...I can't find the same error code in ADF..

Comment: @LearnCocos2D It didn't work...opps

Comment: @JackZeng have you tried resetting the simulator? (all versions)

Comment: @bensarz Yes,I had tried this way, it did not works for me. The only way is changing the version of simulator. PS: I have not a developer account, so I can not use ios8 simulator, is this the reason?

Comment: @JackZeng That's an interesting question. It is unlikely that that is the problem. I have a test application which defines "none" as the team in the build settings and I am able to use the iOS simulator just fine. Do you have the project hosted somewhere I can download and play around?

Comment: @bensarz In fact, even I build an empty project, it still can not work. but in 7.1, it is fine....I will update Xcode beta2 version, have a try later.

Comment: Where did you get the Xcode beta version from if you don't have a developer account?

Comment: I had the same issue, completely exiting Xcode and pulling it back up fixed it.

Answer (score 11):

In my case, I tried to run the app on a iPhone 6 simulator when I got this error. Quitted the simulator only and re-ran the app on iPhone 5s (8.1) - it worked fine.

After a while I changed the target back to iPhone 6 (without quitting it), and ran the app against it - no error shown.

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned in the [Xcode 6.1 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html) and in [my sticky post in the Apple Developer Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/248879?tstart=0) for the iOS Simulator, this is a known bug in iOS.

> Upon installation of an app, SpringBoard will SIGKILL that app's
>   process in order to force a relaunch of the app with the new
>   executable.  The problem is that there is a race condition whereby
>   SpringBoard may accidentally SIGKILL a *new* process that we just
>   launched rather than the old process.  Which of the various error
>   messages you get depends on exactly when in the launch process the
>   SIGKILL was delivered.  Normally, this shouldn't happen, so the advise
>   is to just try again (sorry =/).  If you find that this happes to you
>   all the time or more frequently than you can tollerate, we are
>   incredibly sorry.  We are aware that systems with slower disk I/O will
>   see this happen more frequently than faster systems, so if you are
>   using an NFS home directory, you may want to create a local directory
>   for your simulator data and setup a simlink to it from
>   ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator

Comment: This was very helpful. Exactly what I needed for my NFS home folder.

Answer (score 6):

By Quitting the Simulator and Run the application worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

For me , just Reset Content and setting in your simulator

Answer (score 4):

Restart Mac can solve the problem for me.

Comment: for me it was actually fixed with a restart

Comment: Restarting is irrelevant.  You just needed to retry until it worked.

Comment: Restart actually did help. Thanks. Though my error code was 22 instead of 3.

Answer (score 0):

This error is less severe than "Domain = DTiPhoneSimulatorErrorDomain, Code = 2" error that I had when I switched to Xcode 6.

For this one, I just reset and cleared contents on my Simulator...quit. Rebuilt and ran my app...and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Every time this has happened to me (as of this writing, still happening on Xcode 6.1) I do not need to restart my mac to fix it. Instead I only had to restart the simulator.  I exit the simulator by right-clicking on its icon in the tray and selecting the option to Quit.  The I re-run my app and the simulator starts from scratch and runs my app with no error.  Much quicker than re-starting the mac.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had the same error popping up, but since I force quitted the simulator then ran the project again I got it fixed and running fine. Hope that helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

If this error occurs with **ionic framework**, make sure you have an app id given in your `config.xml`

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic error which says that it is unable to launch the app. The real error is in the log file. Go to the Simulator menu, Debug / Open System Log. Then press Reveal button to open the folder with actual Simulator logs. In my case it was CoreSimulator.log.

Here you will find the real error. My error was Could not register service com.apple.gputools.agent.producer.sim .

After a lot to struggle and trying all suggestions for half a day, I just went to simulator menu and chose File / GPU Selection / Use External GPU when available. That's it.

Answer (score -1):

please download new **xcode_6 beta 4**. your project will work in simulator. As i have tested as well.

Comment: Still a documented issue.  There's no reason to expect it to be fixed until the release notes no longer call out this bug.

Comment: this answer is out of date

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes the beta version of XCode is wrongly configured to use the command line tools from the previous xcode version.
This solution should fix the issue for you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/25415781/512504