# Xcode 6 Beta 3: Simulator Issue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

I am currently experiencing problems launching the Xcode 6 Beta 3 Simulator.  Once I launch the IOS Simulator the error "Unable to boot the IOS Simulator." appears. Following the IOS Simulator error, I then get an error from xcode reading "Unable to run app in Simulator An error was encountered while running (Domain = DTiPhoneSimulatorErrorDomain, Code = 2)".

I went to Xcode/preference/Downloads with intentions of seeing a IOS 8.0 Simulator but there was none. Could this be the problem? Am I suppose to have a IOS 8.0 Simulator? If so can someone direct me how to get it? Also, under the "Downloads" tab in Xcode preference I do see IOS 7.0 and 7.1 Simulators and both work fine with Xocde 5.

Comment: Did you restart computer?

Comment: Yes, I restarted my computer several times. Is there a IOS 8.0 simulator on your computer in Xcode/preference/Downloads? @troop231

Comment: Try to redownload Xcode.

Comment: I've tried that multiple times. Any other suggestions? @dasdom

Comment: Repair file permissions. Reset PRAM.

Comment: Just tried repairing file permissions, no luck.Any other suggestions? @dasdom

Comment: I would suggest deleting all preferences related to Xcode. Yes, you lose all your preferences, but sometimes this is the only way to get going again.

Comment: Including Xcode 5? Or everything Xcode 6 related? @matt

Comment: Had the same issue after update to beta5, simulator reset helped. Again in beta6, nothing help yet. Reinstall few times.

Comment: same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24033417/unable-to-run-app-in-simulator-xcode-beta-6-ios-8

Comment: You can try this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26343201/2091181)

Answer (score 0):

Reset Content and Settings in iOS Simulator, close it, and then build again.