# xcode6.0.1 not able to start ios8 simulator

Tags: xcode

Updated xcode to 6.0.1, ios 8 simulator unable to boot.

I tried in xcode preferences, under download tap, I can only see ios7 simulator and ios 7.1 simulator, no ios 8 simulator available to download from there, I was able to download ios 7 or 7.1 simulator and run test app on simulator, but can't find the way how to make it work with ios8 simulator, does anyone as any ideas?:(

here is my system crash report:

```
Process:         launchd_sim [1385]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/sbin/launchd_sim
Identifier:      launchd_sim
Version:         2.0.0 (560.1.3)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [155]
Responsible:     launchd_sim [1385]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-09-26 11:11:52.309 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.5 (13F34)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  048D18A1-2364-DAD1-67B6-1BF02E5CF5D5


Crashed Thread:  0

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000102c24000-0000000102c5d000 [  228K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/sbin/launchd_sim

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/usr/lib/libimckit.dylib
DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk
DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib
DYLD_FALLBACK_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks
DYLD_SHARED_REGION=avoid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any crash logs (eg: launchd_sim crashes) in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports?  If so, can you provide one of them?

Is there anything interesting in ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/CoreSimulator.log?

---

The issue is that you have DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/usr/lib/libimckit.dylib in your environment.  What is this for?

The iOS 8 simulator will not work on OS X Mavericks if you try to inject host dylibs into the process via DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES.  OS X Yosemite has software changes that will work around this problem and just log the issue rather than crashing.

I suggest that you either upgrade to OS X Yosemite or simply unset DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES (and/or uninstall the rest of the software that is associated with libimckit.dylib).

To make sure that DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES is not set, edit /etc/launchd.conf or $HOME/.launchd.conf (eg: sudo nano -w /etc/launchd.conf).  Look for a relevant 'setenv' line, delete it, save, and reboot your system.

Comment: -Could not register service com.apple.audio.coreaudiod: launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0xfffffecc, I have been trying to make this work nearly a week, still no luck yet

Comment: I edit my question, added crash reports

Comment: After a week of search, this solved my problem, Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Tyr going to the Window menu and selecting 'Devices'. In the window that appears there is a '+' button at the bottom left. You can use this to add more simulator devices hopefully including the iOS 8 ones.

Comment: I tried that, I can see ios8 simulator in xcode, but when I run it, simulator can't boot. tried to delete everything there and add again, still doesn't work. I also tried to restart the macbook, reinstalled xcode as well, but still no luck:(

Comment: Are there any messages, and are there any messages in Console?

Comment: the only message I got from simulator is "unable to boot simulator", The message I got from xcode"An error was encountered while running (Domain = DTiPhoneSimulatorErrorDomain, Code = 2)"

Comment: Have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24727397/xcode-beta-6-ios-8-simulator-not-working

Comment: I have seen that and tried all the solutions there, still not working. even when I create a test project with just helloworld, still doesn't work for ios simulators:(