# Xcode 6, ios 8 simulator will not boot

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I'm getting the following error:

> Error Code: (Domain = DTiPhoneSimulatorErrorDomain, Code = 2)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try opening the Simulator and from the menu select `Reset Content and Settings` then rebuilding your app

Comment: I've tried that, and I restarted my Mac... It did not work.

Comment: Check this: [Xcode beta 6 iOS 8: Simulator not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24727397/xcode-beta-6-ios-8-simulator-not-working) Hope it helps you!

Comment: I couldn't find anything that would work... I've tried nearly everything. Deleting the simulators, restarting the mac, and adding them back in. And then doing what you said. And I deleted Xcode and reinstalled it. @MarckGorgon

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything interesting in ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/CoreSimulator.log?

Do you see an "Unable to boot the iOS Simulator." error message in that log file or in a dialog in iOS Simulator.app?  If so, that is almost always because launchd_crashed because DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES was set to something not compatible with the iOS Simulator runtime.  Do you have any crash logs (eg: launchd_sim crashes) in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports?  If so, check if they show DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES being set.  If that's the case, your options are to either update to an OS X Yosemite host (which will deal with this issue) or unset DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES (likely set in /etc/launchd.conf or ~/.launchd.conf)

Another common cause of this error message is a bug mentioned in the release notes in which the current workaround is to just try again (there is a timing bug during install/launch).

Comment: I did see "Unable to boot the IOS Simulator" in that log file. And when I launch IOS Simulator it does say "Unable to boot the IOS Simulator". And in "~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports" In the '.crash' files I found this "DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/usr/lib/libimckit.dylib". Is that correct?

Comment: Yep.  That's the issue.  See my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962143/xcode6-0-1-not-able-to-start-ios8-simulator/26053165#26053165