# Unable to boot iOS 8 Simulator

Tags: ios8, ios-simulator, xcode6

I have just updated my Xcode to 6.0.1 from Mac App Store, and my OS version is OS X 10.9.5. The problem is that the iOS 8 Simulator is not loading, but the iOS 7 simulator is working fine.

Every time I try to boot an iOS 8 simulator device, I get an error message:

> "Unable to boot iOS Simulator"

Comment: Make sure you choose XCode6 as Command Line Tools in Preferences > Locations Section,look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24033417/unable-to-run-app-in-simulator-xcode-beta-6-ios-8

Comment: You can try: Force quit all other simulator then try to run the iOS8 simulator.

Comment: @ Sport. Thanks..That is selected by default.

Comment: @ souvickcse...Yes I tried that too but no success.

Comment: @Shakti You fixed this issue?

Comment: @PREMKUMAR..No. I am still fighting with it.

Comment: @Shakti Do you any solution I have also same problem. I tried all possible solutions nothing worked for me. Let me know if you got any solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to run app in Simulator: Xcode beta 6 iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24033417/unable-to-run-app-in-simulator-xcode-beta-6-ios-8)

Answer (score 6):

The main cause of this error is that DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES is set.  I suggest you unset DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES (likely in /etc/launchd.conf) or otherwise uninstall the product that set it, and then reboot.

OS X Yosemite has a software change to deal with this situation, so if you need the product that was setting DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES, I suggest you update to OS X Yosemite for your development.

Comment: Just used this technique to rescue a student's laptop! TYVM!

Answer (score -2):

Go into Window->Devices.  Find the simulator that's not working, right click and delete it.  Then click on the "+" button at the bottom and you can add it back in.

I had to delete a few of them, and this only takes a minute.

Comment: You can just reset the device to a fresh state rather than deleting and re-adding by using 'xcrun simctl erase <device udid>' or choosing 'Reset Contents & Settings' from the iOS Simulator's menu.  However, that is not a possible cause for this particular problem.

Comment: I had the same issue with the same symptoms and resetting it didn't help at all.  At least my answer doesn't require installing a new OS. :-/

Comment: Resetting it is the exact same thing as deleting and creating a new device.  When we reset the device, we just delete the existing data directory and copy over the sample content.  Also, I suggest that you take the approach of just unsetting DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES if that is the case rather than jumping to a whole new OS as it's highly likely that you don't actually want whatever code is being injected into your processes.

Comment: Thanks for you comment guys...as I said I have already tried 'Reset Contents & Settings'. I had even Uninstall the Xcode using Terminal commands and reinstall it but yet no success in booting the iOS 8 Simulator.