# Unable to boot the iOS Simulator

Tags: xcode6

I have just installed xCode 6 from the AppStore and every time I open the iOS simulator it shows me this error:

> Unable to boot the iOS Simulator

What can cause this problem and how do I fix it?
(I am using a mid 2011 iMac with OS X Yosemite)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to boot iOS 8 Simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25987302/unable-to-boot-ios-8-simulator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely have DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES set.  Open up Terminal.app and run 'echo $DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES'

If it is set to something, I suggest you unset it (or uninstall whatever set it) when needing to use the iOS Simulator on Mavericks.  I suggest you look at /etc/launchd.conf and $HOME/.launchd.conf as the likely places it is being set from (you'll need to reboot after making changes).

OS X Yosemite has changes to work around this problem, so if you actually need the software that is setting DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES for other reasons, I suggest you use OS X Yosemite.

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/s7HnwQy)

This is what I get when I type echo $DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES

Comment: Do you have any launchd_sim crashes in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports ?  Can you link one of them?

Comment: I don't understand.. What should I do?

Comment: sudo nano -w /etc/launchd.conf ... remove the 'setenv' line, and reboot.

Comment: Delete the entire line.  Not just the "setenv" part of it.  Based on the fact that you have nothing else in there, you can just nuke the file with 'sudo rm /etc/launchd.conf' instead of editing.

Comment: Ok, now what? How do I save it?

Comment: So how do I save it now?

Comment: From nano, you can save with ctrl-o, but as I mentioned in my earlier comment, you're better off just deleting the file.

Comment: Thank you so much! After deleting the file and rebooting it works :)