# Running the app on the simulator shows: "Unable to boot the iOS simulator"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

Running the app on the simulator shows: "Unable to boot the iOS simulator". I'm on Xcode 6.0.1.

I tried everything: resetting the simulator; selecting the Xcode 6.0.1 command line tools; restarting the Mac. The problem is still present.

Comment: Please check this url. I was faced same problem. It was helped me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023029/error-opening-ios-simulator-with-ios-8-beta-version-unable-to-boot-the-ios-sim

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to boot iOS 8 Simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25987302/unable-to-boot-ios-8-simulator)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. In Xcode menu: `Open Developer Tool > iOS Simulator`. When it opens, use the menu to go to `Hardware > Device > Manage Devices...`. In that list, delete the non-working simulators and re-add them.

Also make sure that the `Downloads` section of *Xcode* preferences is up to date.

Comment: I tried this also but still it showing the same problem. When I open simulator click on Hardware > home then also it shows black screen and after some time again same message show.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES set?  If so, this is a dupe of:

[Unable to boot iOS 8 Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25987302/unable-to-boot-ios-8-simulator)

Check /etc/launchd.conf

Comment: From where i can check DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES set?

Comment: As stated in the answer above, "Check /etc/launchd.conf"

Comment: If there is no file /etc/launchd.conf, is it safe to assume that the flag is not set?

Comment: No.  That's just the main place people set it.  Newer versions of the iOS Simulator Runtime ignore invalid DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES, so if you're seeing an issue on newer builds, it's not DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES.