# Unable to boot the iOS Simulator - xcode 6.0.1

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode6

I've an error in Xcode 6.0.1 on OS X Mavericks 10.9.5.

When I debug, the iOS 8 simulator shows this error:

> Unable to boot the iOS Simulator.

After few seconds Xcode shows this other error:

> An error was encountered while running (Domain = DTiPhoneSimulatorErrorDomain, Code = 2)

However, the iOS 7 simulator works!!

Comment: I had a simulator problem today and all I needed to do was quit the simulator and then try again. Maybe that will work...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to boot iOS 8 Simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25987302/unable-to-boot-ios-8-simulator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES set?  Check /etc/launchd.conf and look for launchd_sim crash logs in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports ... if so, this is a dupe of

[Unable to boot iOS 8 Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25987302/unable-to-boot-ios-8-simulator)

Answer (score 0):

At this point there seems to be a lot of problems with the simulator in XCode 6 compared to XCode 5. I've especially seen issues when switching between various deployment targets and simulator devices. Restarting the simulator usually fixes the problem and if not try restarting XCode.

Comment: Most of the issues don't have to do with the simulator itself but rather the OS, unfortunately.  Rather than going back to Xcode 5 for testing, just download and install the iOS 7.1 simulator runtime from Xcode's Downloads (in Xcode's Preferences).  Also, most of the major issues seem to be worked out in iOS 8.2 beta, included in Xcode 6.2 beta.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and found the solution by doing following steps:-

```
 1) Initially i downloaded Xcode 6 library in Documentation section under the path Xcode --> Preferences --> Downloads and restart my xcode but didn't solve my problem. 

After that -> 

2) Downloaded and installed the iOS 7.1 Simulator under the path Xcode --> Preferences --> Downloads. 

        Restart xcode again and the problem solved.

3) I am facing same issue again next morning.

       Unsetting the DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES variable solves my problem:-

 a) Open terminal and type "sudo vi /etc/launchd.conf" command and press Enter
 b) Press I "Insert" mode and change this 

             "setenv DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES /usr/lib/libimckit.dylib" 

                                  to this 

              "unsetenv DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES /usr/lib/libimckit.dylib" 

       and press esc to exit from insert mode. 

    c) Save changes by typing ":wq" Press Enter
    d) Reboot your system and problem soloved.
```

[image]

```
Prior to that i didn't found any iOS version in front of each listed devices 
but after installation or by unsetting DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES variable i found the same in front of each devices.
```

> >
>    [image]

Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks lads, but i finally found a solution.
For those who are still looking for solution, here is the one which helped me:

There is a file /etc/launchd.conf that will not be used by Yoseph. I just deleted it. You can unset DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES environment variable in that file too. Hope this helps you all.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have under the path "Xcode --> Preferences --> Locations --> Command Line Tools --> Xcode 6.0 selected, if not select that.  Another option is under iOS Simulator perform "Reset Content And Settings". Hope this helps!

Comment: Command line tools have nothing to do with the iOS Simulator.