# phonegap - trying a simple helloworld I get just a black screen on iOS emulator

Tags: macos, cordova

I'm following this guidde: http://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/2013/12/19/using-phonegap-3-3-cli-on-mac-os-x-mavericks-to-build-ios-projects/

So when I try `cordova emulate ios` it shows `** BUILD SUCCEEDED **`but iOS Simulator shows a black screen forever, and after some minutes console prints this:

```
Session could not be started: Error Domain=DTiPhoneSimulatorErrorDomain Code=2 "Simulator session timed out." UserInfo=0x7fe1b3f31f00 {NSLocalizedDescription=Simulator session timed out.}
Error: /Users/me/Desktop/TestAppIos/platforms/ios/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:755:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:822:5)
```

I'm on Macbook Retina 13" with Mavericks.

Any idea? I'm just trying to build a helloworld and emulate on android and ios.

Comment: what version of cordova are you using and what version of xcode do you have?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to boot iOS 8 Simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25987302/unable-to-boot-ios-8-simulator)

Answer (score 0):

This error has been reported multiple times on stack overflow.  Every time, it has been caused by DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES being set.  Try deleting /etc/launchd.conf and rebooting.  If the issue persists, please look in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports for any launchd_sim crashes and provide one of those as reference.

Comment: ls: /etc/launchd.conf: No such file or directory

Comment: @Per If you are experiencing this issue (timeout error reported while waiting for the sim to boot) and you don't have DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES set, more information is needed as I stated above.  Please look for launchd_sim crash logs.

Answer (score 0):

What might work is to launch the simulator from Xcode *before* giving the command

```
cordova emulate ios
```

This worked (and still works) for me when I had exactly the same error message. I'm not claiming it will work in all cases.