# Unable to run app in Simulator Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios8, ios-simulator, runtime-error, xcode6

I'm getting an error message while trying to run an application developed in Xcode 5.1 iOS 7.1 on Xcode 6.1 for iOS 8.0. The error state that **'Unable to run app in Simulator**' as show in below screenshot.

I have tried below mentioned solution but none seems to work :

- **Reset the content of simulator**
- **Rebooted mac** after installing Xcode 6.1.
- Xcode -> Preference -> Locations -> **Command Line Tools** : Changed
  Xcode 5.1.1 to 6.1

What might be fix?

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot for solution 2]

[image: Solution 3 tried]

Comment: Did you update the project settings? Xcode 6 pops a warning for this.

Comment: What's the related log output in `/var/log/system.log`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to boot iOS 8 Simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25987302/unable-to-boot-ios-8-simulator)

Answer (score 0):

Delete /etc/launchd.conf if it exists on your system and reboot.  See [Unable to boot iOS 8 Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25987302/unable-to-boot-ios-8-simulator)