# Still getting "Unable to boot iOS Simulator" with Xcode 6

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode6

I have spent about 24 hours on this issue and still can't figure it out.  I've tried everything written in the numerous notes already on this site, all for naught.

I've tried:

- Rebooting my Macbook Air
- Reinstalling Xcode
- Changing the devices inside of iOS Simulator

Does anyone have anymore ideas that may work before I jump ship and just go Android?  (kidding..maybe)

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: launched xcode from applications and  Make sure you choose XCode6 as Command Line Tools in Preferences > Locations Section. Now restart Mac ,Thats it

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  Unfortunately I tried those earlier.  I actually just retired that and it does not work

Comment: Did your configuration ever work?

Comment: Do make sure that you don't have a 3rd-party antivirus that is torpedoing your simulator.  I've had this trouble with other development  environments on Windows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to boot iOS 8 Simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25987302/unable-to-boot-ios-8-simulator)

Answer (score 1):

The overwhelmingly most common cause of this issue is that launchd_sim is crashing immediately.

The overwhelmingly most common cause of launchd_sim crashing immediately is because of your injection of code into every running process via DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES as set in /etc/launchd.conf.

If /etc/launchd.conf exists on your system, remove it and reboot.  You can also just update to OS X Yosemite which no longer supports /etc/launchd.conf.

If that is the root cause, please mark this as a dupe of [Unable to boot iOS 8 Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25987302/unable-to-boot-ios-8-simulator)

If that isn't the root cause, look for launchd_sim crash logs in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports and attach the full contents of one report in an edit to your question, and I will also edit my answer in response.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy!  You are right - it was DYLD-INSERT_LIBRARIES.  I changed this to Uninsert and it works fine now

Comment: Thanks for confirming.  In this case, please flag as a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25987302/unable-to-boot-ios-8-simulator