# Can't create simulator in Xcode 7

Tags: xcode7

When I open Xcode 7.0 beta version, I cannot create a simulator. I click the blue button and nothing happens at all. No error message is displayed and I get no feedback.

[image: Xcode 7 simulator error]

*Xcode -> Preferences - > Downloads* does not show any SDKs to download.
[image: Empty downloads]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Xcode beta version is not using the newest command line tools; you can set the correct version in *Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Command Line Tools*. 
[image: Command Line tools screenshot]

Credit: I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24727397/xcode-beta-6-ios-8-simulator-not-working); it seems like the same error but Xcode 7 doesn't give me an error message (or any feedback)

Comment: Kostia, try my answer.

Answer (score 6):

go to "/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes" and removed the runtimes

This work for me.
Credit: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/11706

Comment: What if "/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes" does not exist? I have Xcode 7.0 from the Mac App Store installed and I can't find such folders.

Comment: @Supertecnoboff look under root/Library, not root/Users/yourname/Library

Comment: it work for me, too.  Thank you very much!  I got the reason from Seancook`s explaination.