# iOS Unable to run app in simulator Xcode 6.1(6A1052d)

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode6

We are buiding an iOS applicaiton in Swift. The XCode we are using is Xcode 6.1(6A1052d).

Our issue is when we run the app in Simulator (5, 5s, 6) the app is not running in the sumulator.

It is giving an error.

Unable to run app in simulator.

An error was encountered while running(Domain = NSPOSIXErrorDomain, Code = 3)

We tried clean & build, delete caches, restart xcode etc. But not worked. We have one other machine with same XCode version. On that machine it works fine.

Any clues?

Tried the solutions given in [Xcode6 can't run any app in simulator ( Domain = NSPOSIXErrorDomain, Code = 3 )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24233589/xcode6-cant-run-any-app-in-simulator-domain-nsposixerrordomain-code-3). But not worked.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [Xcode 6.1 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html) and in [my sticky post in the Apple Developer Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/248879?tstart=0) for the iOS Simulator, this is a known bug in iOS.

> Upon installation of an app, SpringBoard will SIGKILL that app's
>   process in order to force a relaunch of the app with the new
>   executable.  The problem is that there is a race condition whereby
>   SpringBoard may accidentally SIGKILL a *new* process that we just
>   launched rather than the old process.  Which of the various error
>   messages you get depends on exactly when in the launch process the
>   SIGKILL was delivered.  Normally, this shouldn't happen, so the advise
>   is to just try again (sorry =/).  If you find that this happes to you
>   all the time or more frequently than you can tollerate, we are
>   incredibly sorry.  We are aware that systems with slower disk I/O will
>   see this happen more frequently than faster systems, so if you are
>   using an NFS home directory, you may want to create a local directory
>   for your simulator data and setup a simlink to it from
>   ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator

Comment: I am launching the Simulator via the command line, and on some machines, the users observe this error 100% of the time (these are fast, late 2014 MBPs loaded to the hilt). Is there anything you can suggest to reduce the likelihood of hitting this race condition?