# port 8081 already in use when "react-native run-ios"

Tags: react-native

Yes i have read this but still don't know how to make it work.
[react native - Port 8081 already in use, packager is either not running or not running correctly Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30216417/react-native-port-8081-already-in-use-packager-is-either-not-running-or-not-r)

Originally i was doing this

```
1. react-native init Hello
2. react-native run-ios
```

Then hit this "port 8081 already in use".

Did read the react doc, https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/troubleshooting.html

```
1. cannot kill the process using 8081, it keeps on coming back,
   and i don't want to kill it
2. react-native start --port=8088
3. update node_modules/react-
native/React/React.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj file. Did it.
```

Where and which step should i run "react-native start --port=8088" ?

btw, i'm an average engineer, but if i cannot run the very 1st react-native sample in 2 hours, i just cannot see how it can fly, this is very annoying.

Answer (score 9):

In RN 0.55 you can fix this with:

`react-native start --port=1234`

and then in a different window:

`react-native run-ios --port 1234`

Versions:

```
✗ react-native --version
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.55.4
```

Comment: Actually `react-native start --port=1234` is not needed. `react-native run-ios --port 1234` is enough.

Answer (score 2):

**Runing React Native Apps on Mac OS when port 8081 is already in use due to another service or APP**

**For ios emulator**

1. Open Xcode and navigate to Pods -> Development Pods -> React-Core -> Default  -> Base -> RCTDefines
2. Change `#define RCT_METRO_PORT 8081` => `#define RCT_METRO_PORT 8088` or to desired port number (make sure to change all ocurrencies on that file)
3. Run `npx react-native run-ios --port 8088` (or desired port number and needs to match with the one on RCTDefines file) from the project folder

**For Android**

1. Just Runs `npx react-native run-android --port=8088` (or desired port #) from the project folder

Answer (score 1):

In yarn managed project in package.json

```
 "scripts": {
      ...
    "ios": "npx react-native run-ios --port 19001 && npx react-native start --port 19001",
    "android": "npx react-native run-android --port 19001 && npx react-native start --port 19001",
    }
```